# Policy problems with CMake and OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I spent two days trying to fix these problems, I am trying to build for OpenCV using GPU to run my code, because it gets really laggy using CPU.

So these are the problem

```
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:144 (find_package):
Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.`


Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:64 (find_host_package)
cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:271 (find_python)
CMakeLists.txt:643 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.


CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:144 (find_package):
Policy CMP0146 is not set: The FindCUDA module is removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0146" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
set the policy and suppress this warning.`


Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake:21 (find_host_package)
cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:43 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:750 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I've learned that it could be about some new policy and I tried to change `Cmakelist.txt`, but it just doesn't work.

I've tried to reinstall Cmake, but doesn't work either.

And I tried to ignore that to see if it works after all : I went into VS2019, hit "All Build", but it happened to make hundreds of **C1083 Error**.

The Error may be like

```
`C:/Users/擐祆???Documents/OpenCV_Cmake_Document/opencv-4.7.0/modules/imgproc/src/precomp.hpp': No such file or directory opencv_world_AVX512_SKX `
```

I'm Taiwanese so the issue could be caused by the language.

I'm using OpenCV 4.7.0 & Python 3.10.9 and my GPU is Geforce RTC3080.

I tried to ignore the warning, but that does not work.
[image]

Comment: Try with a less bleeding edge version of CMake? The docs say those policies are new in 3.27, which appears still to be in release candidate stage.

Comment: Is it possible for you to place the files in a path that doesn't have taiwanese characters?

Comment: @Micka I don't think that is the case because I'm also facing the same issue now. All of my directories are in alphabet letters

Answer (score 1):

May be you can see 'https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0148.html'.
And I have solved this problem by adding `if(POLICY CMP0148) cmake_policy(SET CMP0148 OLD) endif()`
into **CMakeLists.txt**